# How to write regexp properly?

Tags: php, regex

```
$data = array(
    'core.*',
    'handlers.player.profile',
    'vendor.dummy\.test'
);

$re = '/(?!<\\\\)\./';

foreach ($data as $path) {
    $path = __DIR__ . DS . preg_replace($re, DS, $path) . '.php';
    echo "$path <BR>";
}
```

How should I define regural expression to perform `\.` sequence not to be converted to directory separator (DS is shortcut of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in my project) ?

Comment: As you noticed yourself PHP already knows `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. It's not good practice to re-define already existing identifiers, especially when the only reason is to safe characters. However, what should happen here? Why don't you stay with `/`, which understands _every_ OS?

Comment: I know that ```/``` supported by every OS, but PHP converts slashes in file/directory operations to OS-styled. For example, If I will use ```fopen('./foo/bar.php','r');``` PHP interpreter will convert ```/``` to ```\``` before execution on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Updated, according to comments:

```
php > var_dump(preg_replace('/(?<=[^\\\\])\./', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'vendor.dummy\.test'));
string(18) "vendor/dummy\.test"
```

Comment: Works for me ... I understand that you want any `\` to be replaced with `/`, but only if not preceeded by another back-slash or followed by a dot. Is that not right?

Comment: Convert dot to DS. If backslash is before dot then dot should not be converted to DS.